# How to create Startup class in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new and am studying ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. I am stuck in this error when building a `Startup` class like in my tutorial.

[image: Error unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider']

This is my `Program.cs` class:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

`Startup.cs` class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HCMUE_ASPCore_Lab02
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>
            (
                new PhysicalFileProvider
                (
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")
                )
            );
            services.AddMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

After reading many posts, I know that ASP.NET Core 6's `Program` and `Startup` have changed and my tutorial is old now. But I don't know how to update my `Program` and `Startup` to fit with ASP.NET Core 6.

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: TLDR `services => builder.Services`

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't quite understand your solution. Can you explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is saying that your application is trying to create an instance of `FileUploadController` but it doesn't know how to create an instance of `IFileProvider` to pass into the constructor.

This is a typical dependency injection error, You can register it in this code:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(new PhysicalFileProvider
                (
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")
                ));
```

You can follow this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows) to learn about  `Dependency injection` and other fundamentals in .Net 6.

If you are not comfortable with the new changes in `.Net6`, you can add the `Startup` class according to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-add-startup-cs-class-in-asp-net-core-6-project/).

Answer (score 2):

You want to ensure that both the static file middleware, and any services that inject your file provider, end up using the same instance.

```cs
var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
  Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")
);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(provider);

...

app.UseStaticFiles(
  new StaticFileOptions{ 
    FileProvider = provider
  });
```

But if you don't really need a different file provider, you can instead inject `IWebHostEnvironment` into your controller and reuse the default `.WebRootFileProvider`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Very much appreciate it.